# How to convert text-based subtitles to image-based subtitles?

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitles

I want to convert an `ass` type subtitle track into a `dvd_subtitle` type track.

I know I can't simply ask ffmpeg to convert it with `-c:s dvd_subtitle`, but there must be another simple way, since video players such as `vlc` trivially convert text subtitles to images to display it on the video.

Furthermore, even though `ffmpeg` says it cannot perform such a conversion, I find it hard to believe that it could [burn text subtitles into a video track](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HowToBurnSubtitlesIntoVideo), but not simply convert a text subtitle track into an image subtitle track.

So how do I do this? Is there another program that could perform this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Subtitleedit](https://github.com/SubtitleEdit/subtitleedit) can convert 'text' subtitles to 'image' subtitles. In other, 'ass' to 'vobsub'. 'Vobsub' is composed of 2 files: '.idx' and '.sub':

```
SubtitleEdit.exe /convert sub.ass vobsub
```

ffmpeg supports these files and you can easily get the 'dvdsub' format.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -i sub.idx -map 0 -map 1 -c copy -c:s dvdsub -f mp4 out.mp4
```

This application is accessible in CLI or GUI. GUI has many more options.

Comment: There wouldn't happen to be a Linux version of SubtitleEdit, would there?

Comment: @nc404 Your OS was not specified. But the sources for SubtitleEdit are provided.

Answer (score 1):

[srt2vobsub](https://srt2vobsub.sourceforge.io/) is a command-line tool for linux or other Unix-like systems that generates a pair of .idx/.sub vobsub subtitle files from a textual subtitles file.
Be aware of dependencies (software requirements) and carefully read the description and usage.
Then use ffmpeg as described by Alain 1A45.